# Looking special characters into a strings with AWK

Tags: awk

Need to apply a filter to a file like this:

```
TUPAC_0006:1:1:2554:2356#0/1    0   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   AGAGTTTTAAAATTTCCTTCCATTTCAGTATATGCATACTCAGTTCATCACATAGTAATATCAATAAAAAAATAAA    aK\`Zb_`aaaffdf]ffcfffafddffdffa[ffffcefgfacgggcgedaf[cQ^^_^cc`acadccbgbgcbb    XM:i:0
TUPAC_0006:1:1:4363:2353#0/2    0   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   CNNCNCCATTNATCGGTTACTACTATACTCAATGGATCCAATACCGTTACCAACGGAACAAGTTACCCTAGGGATA    UBBUBT[JTZBHOUIHQGNSVPQYVedcWeHHVK]aee`ca\KaaaLaS\\QW\Qadd_ehhh[cXUIPSaZYW[c    XM:i:0
TUPAC_0006:1:1:3197:2355#0/1    0   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   AGGGCAGAGGACCAACATGGGCATTTTGTTTATGAGCAACGTGGGTCTCA  acY\a\^Sc^`Z^aYff_dYcc^L\]\WRY__dKdYaY\LSIQQO\[W^a  XM:i:0
TUPAC_0006:1:1:3142:2353#0/2    0   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   ACGTCATTTCCACATTCAAAATCCGCAAAGCAGCCAATCACATCGTTCTCTGCAAACTTGTCTCCGTAGTTTTCAA    fffffcffffggggggcgggggggdfgggggcfgggggggggggccRfffgdggafggfffgeffgdWbd]dbdag    XM:i:0
TUPAC_0006:1:1:2463:2357#0/1    16  chr1:20982270-20982592|ENST00000415136.2|100_100    115 255 76M *   0   0   GCTGGGCAGTGAGTGCGGGATTGAGTTTGACGAGGAGAAAACGGCTGTCATTGACCATCACAACTATGACATCTCA    XO^WacPV\[O]`c`_cac^PdadcW]fccacaa\^ZZ`_V_V_R_Wfacfffddfdf^ccafff_cddda^cccY    XA:i:0  MD:Z:76 NM:i:0
TUPAC_0006:1:1:2463:2357#0/2    16  chr1:20982031-20982172|ENST00000415136.2|100_100    17  255 76M *   0   0   GCTGGGCAGTGAGTGCGGGATTGAGTTTGACGAGGAGAAAACGGCTGTCATTGACCATCACAACTATGACATCTCA    XO^WacPV\[O]`c`_cac^PdadcW]fccacaa\^ZZ`_V_V_R_Wfacfffddfdf^ccafff_cddda^cccY    XA:i:0  MD:Z:76 NM:i:0
TUPAC_0006:1:1:2463:2357#0/1    16  chr1:20982273-20982595|ENST00000415136.2|100_100    118 255 76M *   0   0   GCTGGGCAGTGAGTGCGGGATTGAGTTTGACGAGGAGAAAACGGCTGTCATTGACCATCACAACTATGACATCTCA    XO^WacPV\[O]`c`_cac^PdadcW]fccacaa\^ZZ`_V_V_R_Wfacfffddfdf^ccafff_cddda^cccY    XA:i:0  MD:Z:76 NM:i:0
```

I only want to keep the lines that have a 16 on their second field and that their first field finish with /1.

Desired result:

```
TUPAC_0006:1:1:2463:2357#0/1    16  chr1:20982270-20982592|ENST00000415136.2|100_100    115 255 76M *   0   0   GCTGGGCAGTGAGTGCGGGATTGAGTTTGACGAGGAGAAAACGGCTGTCATTGACCATCACAACTATGACATCTCA    XO^WacPV\[O]`c`_cac^PdadcW]fccacaa\^ZZ`_V_V_R_Wfacfffddfdf^ccafff_cddda^cccY    XA:i:0  MD:Z:76 NM:i:0
TUPAC_0006:1:1:2463:2357#0/1    16  chr1:20982273-20982595|ENST00000415136.2|100_100    118 255 76M *   0   0   GCTGGGCAGTGAGTGCGGGATTGAGTTTGACGAGGAGAAAACGGCTGTCATTGACCATCACAACTATGACATCTCA    XO^WacPV\[O]`c`_cac^PdadcW]fccacaa\^ZZ`_V_V_R_Wfacfffddfdf^ccafff_cddda^cccY    XA:i:0  MD:Z:76 NM:i:0
```

I tried to do this with this awk line:

```
 awk '{if ($1 ~ //1/ && $2 == 16) print $0}' file
```

But the character "/" are disturbing the awk syntaxis. So, also I've tried:

```
 awk '{if ($1 ~ /"/1"/ && $2 == 16) print $0}' file
```

but it din't work.

Anybody knows how to find /1 into a string using awk?

An equivalent solution is only filter by the last number of first field. But I don't know how to do it using awk.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '$1~/\/1$/ && $2==16' file
```

---

Use `\/1$` to match `/1` at the end of field#1.